# Android application with different firebase account for different builds

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing an android app for a client. I am building two different builds, one for QA of my company and one for client(live). I want different firebase accounts (for analysis and crash reporting) for these two builds. I have to include google-services.json file in my project for firebase integration. But now I have two accounts and two json files. Should I have to replace json file(according to build type, QA or live) everytime when I am creating build or is there any other dynamic way?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside app folder, create two folders with name Development and Production(folder name(s) must be as name of productFlavors). Now put different google-services.json files respective to productFlavors.